# Displaying Code Snippets Properly Without Escape Characters

Tags: php, mysqli, code-snippets, html-entities

I have a PHP script that stores my code snippets. 
To insert, I use:

```
$snippet_code = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,trim($_POST['snippet_code']));
```

To display, I use the following which is wrapped in a pre tag:

```
$snippet_code = htmlentities($row['SnippetText']);
```

I notice that sometimes I get a lot of escape characters like \\\\ when the snippet is displayed on the page. The escape characters are present wherever single or double quotes appear in the code. The problem seems to be more severe in non-English language browsers.

How can I properly do this? How can I properly store and display code on a page?

Comment: If you don't want entities, don't invoke `htmlentities`. If you do, what is the problem?

Comment: What does "escape characters" mean exactly? Do you take character sets into account?

Comment: @Álvaro G. Vicario, characters like \\\\\\ where single or double quotes are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comments, it seems that you *are* in fact talking about slashes found before quotes.

It's not clear from the limited information you've given us why non-English browsers would show more of these.

However, it *is* likely that these slashes should not be present in the first place. Perhaps you are running `mysql_real_escape_string` several times, instead of just once... but, again, nothing you've shown us indicates that.

Either way, you should fix the data in the database and **not** just hack around the issue on display.

Comment: @usnidorg: I am sorry that you have made that inference, but it's completely baseless. I think that my answer is quite clear: if you are seeing slashes in the output, then you have slashes in your database, and something in your code put them there. It is not possible for us to know what code that was, because you did not show us. Further, the proper solution is to _fix_ that code so that the slashes aren't in the database, rather than applying `stripslashes` to band-aid over the symptom. I hope that's clearer (and that you won't make a habit of getting snarky with people offering free help.)

Comment: @usnidorg: As Álvaro has reminded me, it may be the `magic_quotes` option, not an error in your code, that's adding the extra slashes. Either way, you need to break this problem down. Look at the data in the database: has the problem occurred by that point in the process? Are slashes in the text in your database?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean slash escape sequences like `\"`, and not HTML escape sequences like `&amp;` try this:

```
$snippet_code = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['SnippetText']));
```

If it is actually HTML escapes causing you trouble, just omit the `htmlentities` call.

Comment: What do slashes have to do with anything?

Comment: Stripping slashes here doesn't seem like it would ever be the right solution; when they were added to the original variable, it was for insertion into the database. Any slash present after extracting the data from the database was part of the very original text.

Comment: Well without seeing the rest of his code or output, it's impossible to say what's going on. Hence I provided both solutions.

Comment: @Chriszuma: I'll remove my downvote since it turns out that slashes _are_ relevant, though I still disagree with your answer.

Comment: @Chriszuma, nothing special is going on. I grab the submitted code with mysqli_real_escape_string and display it with htmlentities. No other conversions or sanitation.

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting `'` converted to `\'`, your server is probably configured with a legacy option called `Magic Quotes`. You [can read about it in the PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php). My advice is to [disable them](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php) if possible.

Also, check your database. It's possible that your current data is corrupted. If so, you can write a small script thay uses [stripslashes()](http://php.net/stripslashes) to fix it.

Comment: Excellent, very helpful advice! I wish I could vote on more than one answer.